# In swift ios, how to generate and play (preferably buffered) sound data?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I know how I can play a wav file in swift.

However, I want to generate the audio data myself and play it through swift.

Additionally, I don't want to store the whole 'tune' in memory and then play it because I'm worried that the size of the tune will be too big.

So what I want to do is to use some swift facility that will keep calling a callback method to get the next chunk of data (say a second's worth) when it needs it, so that it can seamlessly play a long tune without me needing a buffer of more than a second's worth of data. There is such a facility in android - I use `AudioTrack` in mode `MODE_STREAM`. Is there an equivalent in swift ios? I'd be hugely grateful if anyone could point me to some sample code.

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/audio_playback_recording_and_processing/avaudioengine), [setManualRenderingInputPCMFormat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioinputnode/2881264-setmanualrenderinginputpcmformat) allows you to feed data through a callback

Comment: @Bill Ah thank you! That looks promising!

Comment: [this](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/blob/master/AudioDeviceExample/AudioDevices/ExampleAVAudioEngineDevice.m) is not really a tutorial, but if you need some sort of example on how to use it, maybe it'll help

Comment: @Bill Great - thank you!